# Reading text from swf with StuartMacKay's transform-swf library

Tags: java, text, flash, text-extraction

I need to extract all the texts from some swf files. I'm using Java since I have a lot of modules developed with this language.
Thus, I did a search through the Web for all the free Java library devoted to handle SWF files.
Finally, I found the library developed by *StuartMacKay*. The library, named **transform-swf**, may be found on GitHub by clicking [here](https://github.com/StuartMacKay/transform-swf).

The question is: **Once I extract the `GlyphIndex`es from a `TextSpan`, how can I convert the glyps in characters?**

Please, provide a complete working and tested example. No theoretical answer will be accepted nor answers like "it cannot be done", "it ain't possible", etc.

**What I know and what I did**
I know that the `GlyphIndex`es are built by using a `TextTable`, which is constructed by recurring to an integer that represente the font size and a font description provided by a `DefineFont2` object, but when I decode all the DefineFont2, all have a zero length advance.

Here follows what I did.

```
//Creating a Movie object from an swf file.
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.decodeFromFile(new File(out));

//Saving all the decoded DefineFont2 objects.
Map<Integer,DefineFont2> fonts = new HashMap<>();
for (MovieTag object : list) {
  if (object instanceof DefineFont2) {
    DefineFont2 df2 = (DefineFont2) object;
    fonts.put(df2.getIdentifier(), df2);
  }
} 
//Now I retrieve all the texts       
for (MovieTag object : list) {
    if (object instanceof DefineText2) {
        DefineText2 dt2 = (DefineText2) object;
        for (TextSpan ts : dt2.getSpans()) {
            Integer fontIdentifier = ts.getIdentifier();
            if (fontIdentifier != null) {
                int fontSize = ts.getHeight();
                // Here I try to create an object that should
                // reverse the process done by a TextTable
                ReverseTextTable rtt = 
                  new ReverseTextTable(fonts.get(fontIdentifier), fontSize);
                System.out.println(rtt.charactersForText(ts.getCharacters()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class `ReverseTextTable` follows here:

```
public final class ReverseTextTable {


    private final transient Map<Character, GlyphIndex> characters;
    private final transient Map<GlyphIndex, Character> glyphs;

    public ReverseTextTable(final DefineFont2 font, final int fontSize) {    
        characters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        glyphs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        final List<Integer> codes = font.getCodes();
        final List<Integer> advances = font.getAdvances();
        final float scale = fontSize / EMSQUARE;
        final int count = codes.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            characters.put((char) codes.get(i).intValue(), new GlyphIndex(i,
                    (int) (advances.get(i) * scale)));
            glyphs.put(new GlyphIndex(i,
                    (int) (advances.get(i) * scale)), (char) codes.get(i).intValue());
        }
    }    

    //This method should reverse from a list of GlyphIndexes to a String
    public String charactersForText(final List<GlyphIndex> list) {
        String text="";
        for(GlyphIndex gi: list){
            text+=glyphs.get(gi);
        }
        return text;
    }        
}
```

Unfortunately, the list of advances from `DefineFont2` is empty, then the constructor of `ReverseTableText` get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem?
I've got the same problem, please let me know ty.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know how to do that in Java. I'm not claiming that it is not possible, I also believe that there is a way to do that. However, you said that there are a lot of libraries that do that. You also suggested a library, i.e. [swftools](http://swftools.org/). So, I suggest to recurr to that library to extract the text from a flash file. To do that you can use [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) just to execute a command line to run that library.

Personally, I prefer [`Apache Commons exec`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) rather than the standard library released with JDK. Well, just let me show you how you should do. The executable file that you should use is "**swfstrings.exe**". Suppose that it is put in "`C:\`". Suppose that in the same folder you can find a flash file, e.g. `page.swf`. Then, I tried the following code (it works fine):

```
    Path pathToSwfFile = Paths.get("C:\" + File.separator + "page.swf");
    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse("C:\" + File.separator + "swfstrings.exe");
    commandLine.addArgument("\"" + swfFile.toString() + "\"");
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValues(new int[]{0, 1}); //Notice that swfstrings.exe returns 1 for success,
                                            //0 for file not found, -1 for error

    ByteArrayOutputStream stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PumpStreamHandler psh = new PumpStreamHandler(stdout);
    executor.setStreamHandler(psh);
    int exitValue;
    try{
        exitValue = executor.execute(commandLine);
    }catch(org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException ex){
        psh.stop();
    }
    if(!executor.isFailure(exitValue)){
       String out = stdout.toString("UTF-8"); // here you have the extracted text
    }
```

I know, this is not exactly the answer that you requested, but works fine.

Comment: Well, your code works. But uses an exe file. It is not full java.

Comment: Here follows my decision. Since I will lost my 200 reputation, I will award them to you. This is because one requirement was that: "Please, provide a complete working example. The code must be tested. No theoretical answer will be accepted nor answers like "it cannot be done", "it ain't possible", etc.". 1) You provided a working example. 2) You didn't gave a theoretical answer. 3) You didn't sayd that my question was impossible to be solved. Hence, regardless you didn't provided an answer using StuartMacKay library, I will award the 200 reputation, but I will not mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to be working on decompiling an SWF in Java now and I came across this question while figuring out how to reverse engineer the original text back.

After looking at the source code, I realise its really straightforward. Each font has an assigned sequence of characters that can be retrieved by calling `DefineFont2.getCodes()`, and the glyphIndex is the index to the matching character in `DefineFont2.getCodes()`.

However, in cases where there are multiple fonts in use in a single SWF file, it is difficult to match each `DefineText` to the corresponding `DefineFont2` because there's no attributes that identifies the `DefineFont2` used for each `DefineText`.

To work around this issue, I came up with a self-learning algorithm which will attempt to guess the right `DefineFont2` for each `DefineText` and hence derive the original text correctly.

To reverse engineer the original text back, I created a class called `FontLearner`:

```
public class FontLearner {

    private final ArrayList<DefineFont2> fonts = new ArrayList<DefineFont2>();
    private final HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>> advancesMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>>();

    /**
     * The same characters from the same font will have similar advance values.
     * This constant defines the allowed difference between two advance values
     * before they are treated as the same character
     */
    private static final int ADVANCE_THRESHOLD = 10;

    /**
     * Some characters have outlier advance values despite being compared
     * to the same character
     * This constant defines the minimum accuracy level for each String
     * before it is associated with the given font
     */
    private static final double ACCURACY_THRESHOLD = 0.9;

    /**
     * This method adds a DefineFont2 to the learner, and a DefineText
     * associated with the font to teach the learner about the given font.
     * 
     * @param font The font to add to the learner
     * @param text The text associated with the font
     */
    private void addFont(DefineFont2 font, DefineText text) {
        fonts.add(font);
        HashMap<Character, Integer> advances = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        advancesMap.put(font.getIdentifier(), advances);

        List<Integer> codes = font.getCodes();

        List<TextSpan> spans = text.getSpans();
        for (TextSpan span : spans) {
            List<GlyphIndex> characters = span.getCharacters();
            for (GlyphIndex character : characters) {
                int glyphIndex = character.getGlyphIndex();
                char c = (char) (int) codes.get(glyphIndex);

                int advance = character.getAdvance();
                advances.put(c, advance);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param text The DefineText to retrieve the original String from
     * @return The String retrieved from the given DefineText
     */
    public String getString(DefineText text) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<TextSpan> spans = text.getSpans();

        DefineFont2 font = null;
        for (DefineFont2 getFont : fonts) {
            List<Integer> codes = getFont.getCodes();
            HashMap<Character, Integer> advances = advancesMap.get(getFont.getIdentifier());
            if (advances == null) {
                advances = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                advancesMap.put(getFont.getIdentifier(), advances);
            }

            boolean notFound = true;
            int totalMisses = 0;
            int totalCount = 0;

            for (TextSpan span : spans) {
                List<GlyphIndex> characters = span.getCharacters();
                totalCount += characters.size();

                int misses = 0;
                for (GlyphIndex character : characters) {
                    int glyphIndex = character.getGlyphIndex();
                    if (codes.size() > glyphIndex) {
                        char c = (char) (int) codes.get(glyphIndex);

                        Integer getAdvance = advances.get(c);
                        if (getAdvance != null) {
                            notFound = false;

                            if (Math.abs(character.getAdvance() - getAdvance) > ADVANCE_THRESHOLD) {
                                misses += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        notFound = false;
                        misses = characters.size();

                        break;
                    }
                }

                totalMisses += misses;
            }

            double accuracy = (totalCount - totalMisses) * 1.0 / totalCount;

            if (accuracy > ACCURACY_THRESHOLD && !notFound) {
                font = getFont;

                // teach this DefineText to the FontLearner if there are
                // any new characters
                for (TextSpan span : spans) {
                    List<GlyphIndex> characters = span.getCharacters();
                    for (GlyphIndex character : characters) {
                        int glyphIndex = character.getGlyphIndex();
                        char c = (char) (int) codes.get(glyphIndex);

                        int advance = character.getAdvance();
                        if (advances.get(c) == null) {
                            advances.put(c, advance);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (font != null) {
            List<Integer> codes = font.getCodes();

            for (TextSpan span : spans) {
                List<GlyphIndex> characters = span.getCharacters();
                for (GlyphIndex character : characters) {
                    int glyphIndex = character.getGlyphIndex();
                    char c = (char) (int) codes.get(glyphIndex);
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                sb = new StringBuilder(sb.toString().trim());
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }

        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.decodeFromStream(response.getEntity().getContent());

FontLearner learner = new FontLearner();
DefineFont2 font = null;

List<MovieTag> objects = movie.getObjects();
for (MovieTag object : objects) {
if (object instanceof DefineFont2) {
    font = (DefineFont2) object;
} else if (object instanceof DefineText) {
    DefineText text = (DefineText) object;
    if (font != null) {
        learner.addFont(font, text);
        font = null;
    }
    String line = learner.getString(text); // reverse engineers the line
}
```

I am happy to say that this method has given me a 100% accuracy in reverse engineering the original String using StuartMacKay's transform-swf library.

Comment: This helped me a lot for such an undocumented task, thanks! But text IS matched up to font so no guesswork needed. Check out the list of `TextSpan` in each `DefineText2`. Each `TextSpan` has an identifier that matches up to a `DefineFont2` identifier. If the span doesn't have an identifier, it's using the same font as the last span.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be difficult on what your trying to achieve, Your trying to secompile the file bur i am sorry to say that its not possible , What I would suggest you to do is to convert it into some bitmap (if possible) or by any other method try to read the characters using [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

There are some [software's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/) which do that, you can also check some [forums](http://www.coderanch.com/t/573236/java/java/optical-character-recognition-OCR-java) regarding that. Because once compiled version of swf is very difficult (and not possible as far as i know). You can check this [decompiler](https://code.google.com/p/asdec/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jpexs/asdec/SWF.java?r=a036d8528388a593bff3e0911ae2e2123317c483) if you want or try using some other languages like the project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16834/How-to-create-a-simple-SWF-decompiler-with-the-Swf)

Comment: BMP!?!?! OCR!?!? No no, there are many non-java software that does text extraction from swf. E.g. [swftools](http://swftools.org/) provides an exe that does the whole job. So, there should be a way to do that in Java.

Comment: Here follows my decision about the bounty. Both answer doesn't accomplish my request. I asked to accomplish the following requirements: "_Please, provide a complete working example. The code must be tested. No theoretical answer will be accepted nor answers like "it cannot be done", "it ain't possible", etc._". Since you missed all the three requirement, I cannot award the 200 reputations to you. Hence, regardless also the other answer didn't provided an answer using StuartMacKay library, I will award the 200 reputation to that answer since followed my guideline. I will not mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with long strings using **transform-swf** library.

Got the source code and debugged it.
I believe there was a small bug in class `com.flagstone.transform.coder.SWFDecoder`.

Line 540 (applicable to version 3.0.2), change

> dest += length;

with

> dest += count;

That should do it for you (it's about extracting strings).
I notified Stuart as well.  The problem appears only if your strings are very large.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you asked but I needed to pull text from SWF recently using Java and found the [ffdec](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler) library much better than [transform-swf](https://github.com/StuartMacKay/transform-swf)

Comment if anyone needs sample code